# Numpy Memory Error when when trying to perform an algebraic operations on arrays

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have two numpy arrays (F1 and F2) of 512x512x128. For each value, different from 0, I need to generate a new value as 1000*(F1-F2)/(F1*(1000+F2)) and store in a matrix. To do that

```
mask = F1>0

F1_m = ma.masked_values(F1,mask)
F2_m = ma.masked_values(F2_re,mask)

result = np.zeros_like(F1)
A =1000*(F1_m-F2_m)
B = np.multiply(F1_m,(1000+F2_m))
result = np.divide(A,B)code here
```

I obtain a memory error.
Thanks,

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and the exact error message. Also, which Python version do you use?

Comment: Please always show the full traceback of the exception in your question. On which line does the error occur?